# Problemas con autorizacion node api

Tags: nodejs

estoy intentando hacer que para la ruta de get users el user deba estar logeado, por lo que del token que se crea en el login deberia poder recobrarlo de los headers. Me puse a crear un middleware de autorizacion pero no puedo obtener el token de los headers. Lo que se me ocurre despues es que del token saque el email del user y poder buscar el rol para por ejemplo crear permisos en creacion de un post por ejemplo.

Middleware hasta ahora en donde me tome undefined:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers["auth-token"];
  console.log('tokens-> ', token);
}
```

mis rutas:

```
    const { Router } = require('express');
    const router = Router();

    const { 
        getAllUsers,
        signupUser,
        signinUser
    } = require('../controllers/user.controller');
    const auth = require('../middleware/auth');

    router.get('/users', auth, getAllUsers);
    router.post('/users/signup', signupUser);
    router.post('/users/signin', signinUser);

    module.exports = router;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En vez de `req.headers["auth-token"]` prueba con `req.get("auth-token")`. No lo pongo como respuesta porque no lo puedo probar yo mismo para saber si funciona. Pero según la [documentación](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) `req` no tiene una propiedad `headers`.

Comment: Vale por el comentario, no me sirvio eso si. De alguna manera por thunder probando la api no puedo tomar el token